# Issues with rake after installing FreeImage on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, freeimage

I am trying to setup my dev environment on my Mac (running Mac OS X 10.6) for my work's rails application. It requires FreeImage and now that I have installed that, I run rake db:migrate and receive the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FreeImage_SetOutputMessage
  Referenced from: /Users/username/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FreeImage_SetOutputMessage
  Referenced from: /Users/username/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

I have tried searching around for the error but am at a complete loss as to where to go or what to try in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: It obviously has something to do with the gem. Reinstall the gem. Make sure the gem is included `gem list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim, I ended up removing the .ruby_inline directory in my home folder and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removing .ruby_inline solved the same issue for me.  On an M2 mac that was migrated via time machine from an intel mac.